# How to get a list of the latest revision number for each file in a Mercurial repository?

Tags: mercurial

I have made a build system for my web application that's rewriting all resource url's to include the file's revision number (to improve client caching). As of today I'm running this command for each file to get the revision number:

```
hg log --template '{rev}\n' path-to-file
```

Executing hg for each file is **really** time consuming. Is there a fast way to list all files in a repository with the latest revision number?

Comment: You're not going to like the answer, but in short this is "svn thinking".  The latest revision number for all files is the same, and it's 'tip'.  Just because a file wasn't altered in a revision doesn't mean that it doesn't have that revision number.  This sounds pedantic, but not.  It's one of the fundamental concepts about the way DVCSs work.

SVN (and predecessors) allowed you to have files at different revisions in checkouts.  Mercurial specifically makes that not possible.  'hg parents doesn't take a file option for a reason.  I urge you to reconsider why you think you need this value.

Comment: Yes and no. We needed something like that to trigger builds on modification of a given part of a repo, for instance. But I still can understand your point.

Comment: @Ry4an As I've mentioned below the revision number works out quite nicely as it's always used by the build server. For some time I just used a random number generated for each file per deployment, but this way the client cache stays valid for multiple deployment cycles without the need for an additional database to track file changes - which is why we have version control systems in the first place right? :)

Comment: Yeah, it's a much better use of last-modded-rev-id than some, but in a perfect world the Last-Modified time on disk (which Mercurial update is careful not to alter unless it should be altered) would be all you need.  Your webserver should provide that header and ideally an ETag built from it along with a Cache-Control header you see to take this caching out of the URL realm.  When RFC2616 works it's a thing of beauty, but browsers, servers, and proxies can collaborate to make it sad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it, but please see my comment above as to why using this anywhere in your workflow is probably a bad idea.  At the very list you should be using the revision hash not the number, since that doesn't change on clone.  Also this isn't terribly efficient, but at least it's only two process instantiations instead of one per file:

```
hg grep --all '.' | perl -na -F: -e 'next unless ($F[2] eq "+"); print "$F[0] $F[1]\n" unless ($prev eq $F[0]); $prev = $F[0]'
```

Example:

```
that 3
file 1
```

Comment: Thanks! Even though it's not *the* most efficient solution it's probably a lot faster than my current approach. I'm using the revision number instead of the hash because it looks a bit nicer and the build always takes place on the same machine.

Comment: Yeah, should be much faster because it only builds one python VM instance instead of many, though it still needlessly trolls through every line of every revision of every file.

Glad it's working for you (hint!). :)

Answer (score 2):

Coding such a command in python, either by parsing hg annotate or as a mercurial extension should not be too difficult. The following [discussion](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/pipermail/mercurial/2010-February/029947.html) on the mercurial mailing-list seems to provide a reasonable solution, although I have not tried it.

Comment: I found that mailing list entry, but I rather not manage and distribute a Mercurial plugin just to do this.

Comment: A mercurial extension is nothing more than a python script anyway :)

Comment: +1 for mercurial extension (less than 30 lines of code)

I improved the mentioned extension to accept revision/branch. https://gist.github.com/2921583

Answer (score 2):

There is a hg debug command "hg debugdata -m REV"  which might help you.  Below is how it work:

1. I commit 3 files a.txt/b.txt/c.txt in changeset 0/1/2/, respectively. And I modify a.txt in rev 3. The DAG looks like this:

------- 0 -------> 1 --------> 2 -------> 3

a.txt      b.txt       c.txt       a.txt

```
 So the newest rev for a/b/c should be 3/1/2;
```

1. After that , the log records are:

   ***hg log -q***

   ```
      3:31308f74291a
      2:8d438b01dfd4
      1:fcc0f041df56
      0:c53934933136
   ```
2. a.txt has two versions, which is linked to changeset 0 and 3 respectively. For every version of a.txt, mercurial will generate a unique hash(nodeid) for it.  These nodeid pertains only to a.txt, and are different from changeset hash. We can use another debug command to see what are those versions:

   ***~/work/hg/a/.hg/store/data$ hg debugindex a.txt.i***

> ```
> rev     offset   length  base  linkrev   nodeid               p1            p2
>
>  0         0       3      0     0        b789fdd96dc2    000000000000  000000000000
>  1         3       6      1     3        a9ecbd92f818    b789fdd96dc2  000000000000
> ```

We can see these two "nodeid" (b789fdd96dc2/a9ecbd92f818) corresponds to changeset version (linkrev) 0/3 respectively. Since these nodeid are hashed based on file contents and parent information(p1/p2), they are "unique" in repository sense. so "b789fdd96dc2" identify a.txt@version-0, and a9ecbd92f818 identify a.txt@version-3.

1. Finally, let us see how "hg debugdata -m REV" work.

This command list a "manifest" of version REV. A manifest is a directory snapshot for all the file@version  that exist in specific changeset REV. Let us see what the manifest is at version 3:

> ***~/work/hg/a$ hg debugdata -m 3***
>
> a.txt^@a9ecbd92f8182efd8eeb5396468fd70884650395
>   b.txt^@1e88685f5ddec574a34c70af492f95b6debc8741
>   c.txt^@149da44f2a4e14f488b7bd4157945a9837408c00

For a.txt, you can see its nodeid is "a9ecbd92f8182efd8eeb5396468fd70884650395", which is a match for the short version nodeid mentioned at step 3. Such nodeid should serve your "rewrite URL" well.

Now you have text name and their nodeid at revision 3.  It only take one debug command to generate all you want. I think this is a better solution.

If you are interested in the debug commands that mercurial provides, do this:

***hg debugcomplete debug***  (list all debug commands)

***hg help debugdata***

***hg help debugindex***

---