# Get last commit for every file of a file list in Mercurial

Tags: find, mercurial

I have an hg repository and I would like to know the last commit date of every file in `sources/php/dracca/endpoint/wiki/**/Wiki*.php`

So far, I have this one liner:

```
find sources/php/dracca/endpoint/wiki/ -name "Wiki*.php" -exec hg log --limit 1 --template "{date|shortdate}" {} \; -exec echo {} \;
```

But this seems utterly slow as (I suppose) `find` makes 1 `hg` call per file, leading to 15seconds of computation for the (say) ~40 files I have in there...

Is there a faster way?

The output of this command looks like:

```
2019-09-20 sources/php/dracca/endpoint/wiki/characters/colmarr/WikiCharactersColmarrEndpoint.php
2019-09-20 sources/php/dracca/endpoint/wiki/characters/dracquints/allgroup/WikiCharactersDracquintsAllgroupEndpoint.php
...
```

It might be changed a bit if needed (I won't mind having, say, 1 date and then the list of files changed for that date, or whatever like this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Even with find+exec you can have shorter (by one last exec) chain with modified template `{date|shortdate}\n`
2. You can use (accepted) perl-ism from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584871/how-to-get-a-list-of-the-latest-revision-number-for-each-file-in-a-mercurial-rep) or ask anybody to update mentioned lof extension to current Mercurial ([code from 2012](https://gist.github.com/2921583) will not work now)

**Alternatives (dirty ugly hacks)**

In any case, you can|have to call hg only once and perform some post-processing of results.

Before these trick, read `hg help filesets` and get one common fileset for your files (I suppose, it *can be* just `set:sources/php/dracca/endpoint/wiki/**/Wiki*.php` but TBT!)

After it, you can:

- Perform hg log like this

  hg log setup.* --template "{files % '{file} {rev} {date|shortdate}\n'}"

(I used simple pattern for test, you have to have own fileset)

get output in such form

```
setup.py 1163 2018-11-07
README.md 1162 2018-11-07
setup.py 1162 2018-11-07
hggit/git_handler.py 1124 2018-05-01
setup.py 1124 2018-05-01
setup.cfg 1118 2017-11-27
setup.py 1117 2017-11-27
hggit/git2hg.py 1111 2017-11-27
hggit/overlay.py 1111 2017-11-27
setup.py 1111 2017-11-27
…
```

(there are some unwanted unexpected files, because I out **all files** in revision, which affect file in interest, without filter). You have to grep only needed files, sort by cols 1+2 and use date of latest revision of each file

- Use `hg grep`. For the above test-pattern

  hg grep "." -I setup.* --files-with-matches -d -q

(find any changes, output only filename+revision, short date)

you'll get something like

```
setup.py:1163:2018-11-07
setup.cfg:1118:2017-11-27
```

and 3-rd column will be your needed last modification date of file

Comment: `hg grep "." -l "set:sources/php/dracca/endpoint/wiki/**/Wiki*.php" -l -d -q` seems to work, but I don't get why having `-l` two times? Still, I've actually fallback on the file's creation/modification dates (because it more suits the actual business need), but this was very interesting (I didn't know about the `%` in template) Thanks!

Comment: @Xenos, it's just bad font here. really it's `I`+ `L` lowercased (replaced by long option in answer)

Comment: Maybe templating for grep will be useful `-T"{files}\t{date|shortdate}\n"`

Comment: Oh, indeed, I'm dumb, thanks for the outline of `I` vs `l`. `hg grep -ldq "<" "set:sources/php/dracca/endpoint/wiki/**/Wiki*.php"` returns what I expect ("<" will always appear in these php files) so thanks again : )